# confused with reading files and storing in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, command-line

I have to write a function where it receives 2 filenames as command line arguments (file1 file2), reads in these files, and store in two `std::vector` containers.

file1 has 4 `int` values in each line, representing a rectangle's bottom point then top point, eg `73 4 113 46` so `x y x y`. I have to write a class for representing the rectangle, which makes each rectangle an object of that class.

file2 just contains a list of areas, 1 per line, in `int` value.

I have to use C++11 to write this function.

Can you please show me an example of how to implement this in
`int main(int argc, char *argv[ ] )`?

I am a total noob to this.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <fstream> // for file-access
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    if (argc > 1) {
        cout << "argv[1] = " << argv[1] << endl; 
    } else {
        cout << "No file name entered. Exiting...";
        return -1;
    }
    ifstream infile(argv[1]); //open the file

    if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()) {
        cout << "File is now open!\nContains:\n";
        string line = "";
        while (getline(infile, line)){
            cout << line << '\n';
        }

    } else {
        cout << "Failed to open file..";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? You know how to check `argv` for parameters, and you know how to open files and read lines. So all that is left is to parse values from lines (look at `std::istringstream`) and add values into a vector (look at `std::vector::push_back()`) .

Answer (score -1):

So you want to start your Program by calling ifstream and put it into a string so that It could be interpretable.

```
//calls the 2nd line in command line 
std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
//puts file into a string
std::string file1;
file>>file1;
```

You have to work out the rest of the details after that. Here is a useful website I used for when I was a cpp noob.

```
http://www.cplusplus.com/
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this as it doesn't even attempt to answer the question asked.